# About the Gershgorin theorem implying diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, gershgorin-sets

This is rather a simple question.

I know that if I have a $n\times n$ matrix and I have $n$ circles, all disjoint with each other, then that matrix is diagonalizable.

So, why is that true?

Comment: I assume you mean that the $n$ Gershgorin disks of your matrix are *pairwise* disjoint. Then a somewhat involved strengthening implies that each of these disks contains one eigenvalue of your matrix, so there are $n$ eigenvalues. A matrix with $n$ eigenvalues is diagonalizable.

Comment: The diagonalization theorem says that an n×n matrix A is diagonalizable if and only if A has n linearly independent eigenvectors so that it can be written in the form A=PDP^(−1). https://mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211oh/m211oh66.pdf

Comment: Here's a good read on the matter:  https://cklixx.people.wm.edu/ELA-LiZhangMS4123.pdf  .  Idea is collect eigenvalues of $A$ in diagonal $D$ and consider $B(p) = (1-p)\cdot A + p\cdot D$ for $p\in[0,1]$.  G.discs contract as $p$ increases.  The easy finish is to compute a winding number on the boundary of each disc @ p=0 and notice it is constant (=1 in you case) for all $p \in (0,1]$.  Using topological continuity or re-running the above with a slightly larger closed path (that does not intersect any disc boundary) then implies the result for p=0 -- i.e. roots in a given disc is constant = 1